# How to add elements to a list every nth round?

Tags: list, sml, ml, mosml

I need to
Write a function `separate` of type `int * 'a * 'a list -> 'a lst` such that
`separate (k, x, l)` returns the list that inserts element `x` after each `k` elements of list `l` (counting from
the end of the list). For example, `separate (1, 0, [1,2,3,4])` should return `[1,0,2,0,3,0,4]` and
`separate (3, 0, [1,2,3,4])` should return `[1,0,2,3,4]`.

So far, this is what I have, but it is causing an error. Can anyone help me?

```
fun separate (k: int, x: 'a, l: 'a list) : 'a list =
   let val count:int = k
    in foldr(
        (fn (h, t) =>
            if count = 0
            then count := 1 in
               x::h::t 
            else count = count + 1 : int
                h::t
            )
```

Comment: `count := 1 in` isn't the way to do something like `let val count = 1 in` Also, you seem to be thinking imperatively. Are you trying to *mutate* count?

Comment: yes, I am trying to decrement count every time I look at an element of the list, starting from the back and moving to the start. once count is zero, we know that we are where we need to be, and then will insert the element at that position in the list. I'm having a hard time not thinking imperatively as well. Is there a way to do this without foldl/foldr? I was using either one because it seemed to simplify the problem.

Comment: Values are immutable in pure functional programming. What do you even *mean* by "decrement the count"? If you want to do something like that, you would need to make `count` one of the arguments of a function (either of the main function or perhaps a helper function).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the logic is quite right, but it should be implemented by passing changed state into another iteration of `foldr` due to immutability:

```
fun separate (k: int, x: 'a, l: 'a list) : 'a list =
  #2 (foldr (fn (h, (count, t)) =>
      if count = 0
      then (k - 1, h::x::t)
      else (count - 1, h::t)
    ) (k, []) l);
```

Thus, instead of initiating `count` as a variable, we initiate `foldr` with tuple `(k, [])` (where `k` is the initial value of `count` and `[]` is the resulting list) and then decrease the count every step of the iteration.